# ODI to BI EE, LKM can't load data

Tags: oracle

I Try load data from `ODI 12c to OBIEE 12c`, I use reverse engineer and Knowledge Modules. I create connect from `ODI to OBIEE`, but after run mapping which should create new table and insert data I get

```
WARNING: SQLCommand execution failure: java.io.IOException: prepare query failed[nQSError: 43113] Message returned from OBIS.
[nQSError: 27002] Near <table>: Syntax error [nQSError: 26012] .
Failed query text:
drop table "Sample Targets Lite"...C_0DEFAULT  
Feb 04, 2019 11:39:08 PM oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.sql.SQLCommand
WARNING: SQLCommand execution failure: java.io.IOException: prepare query failed[nQSError: 43113] Message returned from OBIS.
[nQSError: 27002] Near <table>: Syntax error [nQSError: 26012] .
Failed query text:
create table "Sample Targets Lite"...C_0DEFAULT
(DEPARTMENT_NAME    VARCHAR(30) 
);  
Feb 04, 2019 11:39:09 PM oracle.odi.agent
WARNING: Agent Internal encountered an error: ODI-1226: Step Physical_STEP fails after 1 attempt(s).
Feb 04, 2019 11:39:09 PM oracle.odi.agent
SEVERE: Session ggfgfggf_Physical_SESS (59) fails with return code ODI-1298.
ODI-1217: Session ggfgfggf_Physical_SESS (59) fails with return code ODI-1298.
ODI-1226: Step Physical_STEP fails after 1 attempt(s).
ODI-1227: Task SERIAL-MAP_MAIN- fails on the source connection <Empty Value>.
ODI-1298: Serial task "SERIAL-MAP_MAIN- (10)" failed because child task "SERIAL-EU-LS_HR_CLASS_PROJECT_1_UNIT (20)" is in error.
ODI-1298: Serial task "SERIAL-EU-LS_HR_CLASS_PROJECT_1_UNIT (20)" failed because child task "Create work table-LKM SQL to SQL (JYTHON)- (40)" is in error.
ODI-1228: Task Create work table-LKM SQL to SQL (JYTHON)- fails on the target connection BI_connect.
Caused By: java.sql.SQLException: java.io.IOException: prepare query failed[nQSError: 43113] Message returned from OBIS.
[nQSError: 27002] Near <table>: Syntax error [nQSError: 26012] .
    at oracle.bi.jdbc.AnaJdbcStatementImpl.executeQuery(AnaJdbcStatementImpl.java:387)
...

Feb 04, 2019 11:39:09 PM oracle.odi.agent
SEVERE: Agent  encountered an error: ODI-1217: Session ggfgfggf_Physical_SESS (59) fails with return code ODI-1298. Caused by: ODI-1226: Step Physical_STEP fails after 1 attempt(s).
Feb 04, 2019 11:58:51 PM null
INFO: Disconnecting from Source.
Feb 04, 2019 11:58:51 PM null
INFO: Disconnecting from Repository
Feb 04, 2019 11:58:51 PM null
INFO: Reverse End.
```

I use all LKM but all throw same error or can't run.

Comment: Please copy the error to your question with proper [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). If the link of that image ever changes, the value of your question disappears, and it is not the [only reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/9269043)

Comment: @Vasilisa i hope this is good :)